# karate ui match alert text

Tags: karate, messagebox

I am tring to check an alert message and it does not work.

This is the code :
`Then match driver.dialog == "Trigger type not chosen"`

This is the error :
`match failed: EQUALS $ | data types don't match (OTHER:STRING) com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.dialog 'Trigger type not chosen'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue in our documentation, try `driver.dialogText`:

Can you try this:

```
* match driver.dialogText == "Trigger type not chosen"
```